# Bar plot with logarithmic y axis in PGFPlots: how to shift bar bottoms

Tags: tikz, pgfplots

I want to make a bar plot in PGFPlots with a logarithmic y axis. The issue I have is that the bar bottoms are drawn relative to `10^0`, when I want the bottoms at something below `ymin`. See below:

[image]

In other words, there should be no gap between the bottom x axis spine and the bars. Is there any way to accomplish this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}
    \addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(0, 10) (1, 0.01)};
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the `log origin` option, as suggested by [this answer over on TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86680/pgfplots-and-log-scale-bars-starting-from-the-bottom-of-the-screeen):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[log origin=infty]
    \addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(0, 10) (1, 0.01)};
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even realize I wasn't on TeX.SE.